# Symfony multiple requests to FOS Routing

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony 2 project that is a bit slow to load. The page is a bit heavy, but I still found it weird to be so slow.

I checked the network inspector in Firefox and noticed that about half the loading time was cause by multiple calls to `routing?callback=fos.Router.setData`, each time returning an identical javascript.

For instance, one time there were 12 calls that took 1.92 seconds out of the total 3.84 seconds, effectively doubling the already long loading time...

What are these FOS scripts and why do I need so many of them? Is there something wrong in my Symfony 2 configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FOSRouting` while serving routes can work in two ways:

1. Calling controller which generates routes every request (on the fly). This is convenient for dev environment as it is not cached.
2. Routes can be dump into static js with `php app/console fos:js-routing:dump` command.

It seems that you're using option number one. Try to use second - this will dump your routes into static js file which will be served instead of controller call. Read [docs](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#fosjs-routingdump) how to do that.

To keep convenience in `dev` env and performance at `prod` env you can use this kind of code to include your routes. Just remember to run `fos:js-routing:dump` command every deploy to prod:

```
{% if app.debug %}
       <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
{% else %}
    {% javascripts 'js/fos_js_routes.js' %}
       <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Quite a costly convenience. Yes, it seems each request corresponds to one path being resolved. Thank you.